# HttpClient: Certificate for www.recaptcha.com doesn't match any of the subject alternative names

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, recaptcha, apache-httpclient-4.x, subject-alternative-name

Trying to Post a http request to https://www.recaptcha.com,

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.recaptcha.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");         
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Apache httpclient version 4.5.3.

got error:

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <www.recaptcha.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [google.com, *.2mdn.net, *.android.com, *.appengine.google.com, *.au.doubleclick.net, *.bdn.dev, *.cc-dt.com, *.cloud.google.com, *.crowdsource.google.com, *.datacompute.google.com, *.de.doubleclick.net, *.doubleclick.com, *.doubleclick.net, *.flash.android.com, *.fls.doubleclick.net, *.fr.doubleclick.net, *.g.co, *.gcp.gvt2.com, *.gcpcdn.gvt1.com, *.ggpht.cn, *.gkecnapps.cn, *.google-analytics.com, *.google.ac, *.google.ad, *.google.ae, *.google.af, *.google.ag, *.google.ai, *.google.al, *.google.am, *.google.as, *.google.at, *.google.az, *.google.ba, *.google.be, *.google.bf, *.google.bg, *.google.bi, *.google.bj, *.google.bs, *.google.bt, *.google.by, *.google.ca, *.google.cat, *.google.cc, *.google.cd, *.google.cf, *.google.cg, *.google.ch, *.google.ci, *.google.cl, *.google.cm, *.google.cn, *.google.co.ao, *.google.co.bw, *.google.co.ck, *.google.co.cr, *.google.co.hu, *.google.co.id, *.google.co.il, *.google.co.im, *.google.co.in, *.google.co.je, *.google.co.jp, *.google.co.ke, *.google.co.kr, *.google.co.ls, *.google.co.ma, *.google.co.mz, *.google.co.nz, *.google.co.th, *.google.co.tz, *.google.co.ug, *.google.co.uk, *.google.co.uz, *.google.co.ve, *.google.co.vi, *.google.co.za, *.google.co.zm, *.google.co.zw, *.google.com, *.google.com.af, *.google.com.ag, *.google.com.ai, *.google.com.ar, *.google.com.au, *.google.com.bd, *.google.com.bh, *.google.com.bn, *.google.com.bo, *.google.com.br, *.google.com.by, *.google.com.bz, *.google.com.cn, *.google.com.co, *.google.com.cu, *.google.com.cy, *.google.com.do, *.google.com.ec, *.google.com.eg, *.google.com.et, *.google.com.fj, *.google.com.ge, *.google.com.gh, *.google.com.gi, *.google.com.gr, *.google.com.gt, *.google.com.hk, *.google.com.iq, *.google.com.jm, *.google.com.jo, *.google.com.kh, *.google.com.kw, *.google.com.lb, *.google.com.ly, *.google.com.mm, *.google.com.mt, *.google.com.mx, *.google.com.my, *.google.com.na, *.google.com.nf, *.google.com.ng, *.google.com.ni, *.google.com.np, *.google.com.nr, *.google.com.om, *.google.com.pa, *.google.com.pe, *.google.com.pg, *.google.com.ph, *.google.com.pk, *.google.com.pl, *.google.com.pr, *.google.com.py, *.google.com.qa, *.google.com.ru, *.google.com.sa, *.google.com.sb, *.google.com.sg, *.google.com.sl, *.google.com.sv, *.google.com.tj, *.google.com.tn, *.google.com.tr, *.google.com.tw, *.google.com.ua, *.google.com.uy, *.google.com.vc, *.google.com.ve, *.google.com.vn, *.google.cv, *.google.cz, *.google.de, *.google.dj, *.google.dk, *.google.dm, *.google.dz, *.google.ee, *.google.es, *.google.eus, *.google.fi, *.google.fm, *.google.fr, *.google.frl, *.google.ga, *.google.gal, *.google.ge, *.google.gg, *.google.gl, *.google.gm, *.google.gp, *.google.gr, *.google.gy, *.google.hk, *.google.hn, *.google.hr, *.google.ht, *.google.hu, *.google.ie, *.google.im, *.google.in, *.google.info, *.google.iq, *.google.ir, *.google.is, *.google.it, *.google.it.ao, *.google.je, *.google.jo, *.google.jobs, *.google.jp, *.google.kg, *.google.ki, *.google.kz, *.google.la, *.google.li, *.google.lk, *.google.lt, *.google.lu, *.google.lv, *.google.md, *.google.me, *.google.mg, *.google.mk, *.google.ml, *.google.mn, *.google.ms, *.google.mu, *.google.mv, *.google.mw, *.google.ne, *.google.ne.jp, *.google.net, *.google.ng, *.google.nl, *.google.no, *.google.nr, *.google.nu, *.google.off.ai, *.google.pk, *.google.pl, *.google.pn, *.google.ps, *.google.pt, *.google.ro, *.google.rs, *.google.ru, *.google.rw, *.google.sc, *.google.se, *.google.sh, *.google.si, *.google.sk, *.google.sm, *.google.sn, *.google.so, *.google.sr, *.google.st, *.google.td, *.google.tel, *.google.tg, *.google.tk, *.google.tl, *.google.tm, *.google.tn, *.google.to, *.google.tt, *.google.ua, *.google.us, *.google.uz, *.google.vg, *.google.vu, *.google.ws, *.googleadapis.com, *.googleadsserving.cn, *.googleapis.cn, *.googlecnapps.cn, *.googlecommerce.com, *.googleusercontent.cn, *.googlevideo.com, *.gstatic.cn, *.gstatic.com, *.gstaticcnapps.cn, *.gvt1.com, *.gvt2.com, *.jp.doubleclick.net, *.metric.gstatic.com, *.uk.doubleclick.net, *.urchin.com, *.url.google.com, *.wear.gkecnapps.cn, *.youtube-nocookie.com, *.youtube.com, *.youtubeeducation.com, *.youtubekids.com, *.yt.be, *.ytimg.com, ad.mo.doubleclick.net, android.clients.google.com, android.com, developer.android.google.cn, developers.android.google.cn, doubleclick.com, doubleclick.net, g.co, ggpht.cn, gkecnapps.cn, goo.gl, google-analytics.com, google.ac, google.ad, google.ae, google.af, google.ag, google.ai, google.al, google.am, google.as, google.at, google.az, google.ba, google.be, google.bf, google.bg, google.bi, google.bj, google.bs, google.bt, google.by, google.ca, google.cat, google.cc, google.cd, google.cf, google.cg, google.ch, google.ci, google.cl, google.cm, google.cn, google.co.ao, google.co.bw, google.co.ck, google.co.cr, google.co.hu, google.co.id, google.co.il, google.co.im, google.co.in, google.co.je, google.co.jp, google.co.ke, google.co.kr, google.co.ls, google.co.ma, google.co.mz, google.co.nz, google.co.th, google.co.tz, google.co.ug, google.co.uk, google.co.uz, google.co.ve, google.co.vi, google.co.za, google.co.zm, google.co.zw, google.com.af, google.com.ag, google.com.ai, google.com.ar, google.com.au, google.com.bd, google.com.bh, google.com.bn, google.com.bo, google.com.br, google.com.by, google.com.bz, google.com.cn, google.com.co, google.com.cu, google.com.cy, google.com.do, google.com.ec, google.com.eg, google.com.et, google.com.fj, google.com.ge, google.com.gh, google.com.gi, google.com.gr, google.com.gt, google.com.hk, google.com.iq, google.com.jm, google.com.jo, google.com.kh, google.com.kw, google.com.lb, google.com.ly, google.com.mm, google.com.mt, google.com.mx, google.com.my, google.com.na, google.com.nf, google.com.ng, google.com.ni, google.com.np, google.com.nr, google.com.om, google.com.pa, google.com.pe, google.com.pg, google.com.ph, google.com.pk, google.com.pl, google.com.pr, google.com.py, google.com.qa, google.com.ru, google.com.sa, google.com.sb, google.com.sg, google.com.sl, google.com.sv, google.com.tj, google.com.tn, google.com.tr, google.com.tw, google.com.ua, google.com.uy, google.com.vc, google.com.ve, google.com.vn, google.cv, google.cz, google.de, google.dj, google.dk, google.dm, google.dz, google.ee, google.es, google.eus, google.fi, google.fm, google.fr, google.frl, google.ga, google.gal, google.ge, google.gg, google.gl, google.gm, google.gp, google.gr, google.gy, google.hk, google.hn, google.hr, google.ht, google.hu, google.ie, google.im, google.in, google.info, google.iq, google.ir, google.is, google.it, google.it.ao, google.je, google.jo, google.jobs, google.jp, google.kg, google.ki, google.kz, google.la, google.li, google.lk, google.lt, google.lu, google.lv, google.md, google.me, google.mg, google.mk, google.ml, google.mn, google.ms, google.mu, google.mv, google.mw, google.ne, google.ne.jp, google.net, google.ng, google.nl, google.no, google.nr, google.nu, google.off.ai, google.pk, google.pl, google.pn, google.ps, google.pt, google.ro, google.rs, google.ru, google.rw, google.sc, google.se, google.sh, google.si, google.sk, google.sm, google.sn, google.so, google.sr, google.st, google.td, google.tel, google.tg, google.tk, google.tl, google.tm, google.tn, google.to, google.tt, google.ua, google.us, google.uz, google.vg, google.vu, google.ws, googlecnapps.cn, googlecommerce.com, gstatic.com, source.android.google.cn, urchin.com, www.goo.gl, youtu.be, youtube.com, youtubeeducation.com, youtubekids.com, yt.be]
at

```
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:467)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:397)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762760/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-certificate-doesnt-match-any-of-the-subject-alterna

Comment: Upgrade HttpClient to something more recent.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.recaptcha.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
> ```

The problem is that you are using the wrong URL. It should be instead `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`. See also [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).
And for global access `www.recaptcha.net` should be used, not `www.recaptcha.com` (`.net` vs. `.com`).

Comment: but www.recaptcha.com is for global access, according to https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-use-recaptcha-globally

Comment: @Sunnyday: They write about `www.recaptcha.net` not `www.recaptcha.com` there - i.e. `.net` vs `.com`.

Comment: After changing the domain to www.recaptcha.net, the captcha could not render on screen, showing error: Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865671/recaptcha-domain-www-recaptcha-net-not-working