# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <g.i.t.n.c.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.t.n.c.com]

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

Why I'm getting this error, while the host I'd like to establish the ssl connection with matches the wildcard from the Alternative names field of the certificate?

We use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: **It doesn't match.** _In a cert_ wildcard '*' matches only _one_ DNS level (or formally label), not multiple and not zero. See [RFC6125](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) and if HTTPS [RFC2818](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-3.1)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 please post that as the official answer!